# Saving csv files from databricks to Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I have set up a connection to my Azure Blob Storage from Azure Databricks and I'm able to save files to blob storage from databricks. However, the problem is that I cannot specify the name of the files that I save. The command I use to save the file is:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header",True).("overwrite").csv("wasbs://my-blob-container@prod.blob.core.windows.net/folder/")
```

If I try to specify the `name` as below:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header",True).("overwrite").csv("wasbs://my-blob-container@prod.blob.core.windows.net/folder/name.csv")
```

I simply get a new subfolder with the name `name.csv` - how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to solve the issue of  saving to AzureBlob Storage from Azure Databricks.
You can follow these steps.
For example I have two sample data frames
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

**Create SparkSession**
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

**Create  data frame 1**

```
data1 = [("Alice", 25), ("Bob", 30), ("Charlie", 35)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ["Name", "Age"])
```

**Create data frame 2**

```
data2 = [("Dave", 40), ("Eve", 45), ("Frank", 50)]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ["Name", "Age"])
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am writing these 2 dataframes into ADLS. in .csv format.
To save the data frames to Azure Blob Storage, you can use the write method and specify the target folder path.
Since you want to specify the name of the files, you will need to make use of the partitionBy option.

**Save data frame 1 with a specific file name**

```
df1.write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Name").csv("abfss://folder1@adlsgen2may15.dfs.core.windows.net/df1")
```

**Save data frame 2 with a specific file name**

```
df2.write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Name").csv("abfss://folder1@adlsgen2may15.dfs.core.windows.net/df2")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: But this does not change the name of the csv file in the specific folder but only creates a subfolder for each individual partition.